# How to get row count based on other column groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, rowcount

I need to count the number of dates with which the invoices are made to certain customers in each month

Consider the table named Table1

```
Branch  Month  Date     Amount
----------------------------------------
 B1     April  01/04/20  10000
 B1     April  14/04/20  13000
 B1     May    01/05/20  25000
 B1     May    14/05/20  23000
```

I tried the folllowing code

```
Select 
    Branch, Month, Date, Amount,
    Row_Number() over (partition by Branch order by Month) as rowcount 
from table1
```

and the result was

```
Branch  Month  Date      Amount   rowcount
----------------------------------------
 B1     April  01/04/20  10000      1
 B1     April  14/04/20  13000      2
 B1     May    01/05/20  25000      3
 B1     May    14/05/20  23000      4
```

The result I need should count the column named branch based on column month, the desired result is

```
Branch  Month  Date      Amount   rowcount
---------------------------------------------
 B1     April  01/04/20  10000     1
 B1     April  14/04/20  13000     2
 B1     May    01/05/20  25000     1
 B1     May    14/05/20  23000     2
```

Here rowcount is based on both column branch and Month, how can I get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to partition by `month`.  Something like this:

```
row_number() over (partition by Branch, month order by Month)
```

Note that `month` is repeated.  An `order by` is needed in SQL Server, so you need *something*.  Other options are:

```
row_number() over (partition by Branch, month order by (select null))
row_number() over (partition by Branch, month order by date)
```

I suspect the last is what you really want.